# Word Mail Merge with Underscore in value

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

I have an application that exports rows from a database and does an automated word mail merge.

99% of the time this works exactly as expected. I have noticed that when the `email` field has an underscore somewhere within the value i.e `(user_name@hotmail.com)` the Header Record Delimiter dialog box appears.

When I click OK the process continues as expected and the mail marge completed as expected.

Is there anything I can do to force Word not to prompt me, or encode the underscore differently?

I am using MS-Word 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By encasing the csv values in double quotes MS word doesn't prompt when there is an option of record delimiter